# Using PHP can I use a JDBC or ODBC connection?

Tags: php, jdbc

I have a PHP application that I want to switch from MySQL to Cache DB. I was wondering if I could somehow use a JDBC or ODBC connection since Cache doesn't come with a PHP connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP can use ODBC connections, either [directly](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) or through [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (recommended) using [PDO_ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php).

PDO is recommended because it's easier to switch between databases if you use it... it's similar in concept to JDBC that way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient method, but take a look at the PHP-Java Bridge http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/