# How to connect hive server with php

Tags: php, web-services, hadoop, hive, thrift

I have installed **Hadoop** 2.7 and **Hive** 1.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 that manage sensor data. I have already stored data sensor to Hive.
My Project is to make a web server from it and a web application that can show data record from hive table.
My problem is How to connect database **Hive** with **php**? I found **Apache Thrift** to do that. but I dont understand (Im new at Hadoop things)
Can someone give me tutorial or step by step to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to try is to use ODBC. If you do not know, how to use ODBC. Read more on that via: [Using PHP can I use a JDBC or ODBC connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813450/using-php-can-i-use-a-jdbc-or-odbc-connection)

Once, you can setup your ODBC connection, you can use ODBC to connect to the hiveserver. To install, ODBC here two links on how to do that on Cloudera resp. Hortonworks.

http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/odbc/2-5-12.html
http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-the-hortonworks-odbc-driver-on-windows-7/