# JDBC connection URL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, jdbc

I have the jdbc connection string url i used in java

```
jdbc:sqlserver://DB-1\LDAP;databaseName=LDAPINFO
```

with username and password.

how to connect it in PHP? seem like i cant use JDBC in PHP?

Comment: Do you really need to use `JDBC`?

Comment: no but what extension can connect to that url?

Comment: You can use [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 4):

As defined [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-key-difference-between-JDBC-and-ODBC)*(emphasized by me)*:

> ODBC is an open interface which can be used by any application to communicate with any database system, while **JDBC is an interface that can be used by Java applications** to access databases. Therefore, **unlike JDBC**, ODBC is language independent.

So I don't think it is possible to use `JDBC` for `PHP`, you can use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead to connect to database.

You can also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813450/using-php-can-i-use-a-jdbc-or-odbc-connection) for more reference.

Comment: can u take an example for the url above . I'm new in PHP and now try to read the doc :D